# c# Trying to dispose of timer that exited - System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, timer

i didnt really know how to word the title but i have created a system timer on another thread in a class which, long story short, sends information via tcp ip. I then disconnect the client without stopping the timer so its still running but yet i have exited it so i get the execption "System.ObjectDisposedException" 10 times a second.

I understand why this is happenening but i dont know how to dispose of it because it wont exist so i cant just say Timer.Stop();. I did try to research and found i should use an invoke or something but couldnt get that working. i Have some example code below just for reference.

```
    static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            test RunTimer = new test();
            RunTimer.StartTimer();

        }).Start();

    Application.Run();
    }
}

class test
{
    public static System.Timers.Timer TimerVideo = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        TimerVideo.Interval = 100;
        TimerVideo.Elapsed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Running");
        TimerVideo.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take `static` off of `TimerVideo`. Now each instance of `test` "owns" its own `Timer`.

Then, since `test` owns that disposable resource, make `test` implement `IDisposable`, and ensure that when `test` is disposed the `Timer`is also disposed.

Comment: ok i took static off but i also have a function in the class that properly stops it while im still connected which is just Timer.Stop but since its static i cant access it now, how would i stop the timer from the same class?

Comment: oh wait no im an idiot i just make that function public, perfect i will try this now, thankyou :)

Comment: i tried to implement IDispoable but it didnt do anything

Comment: One `test` is `IDisposable` then you just need to make sure it gets disposed. It's not clear to me from the code when `test` is supposed to go out of scope and get disposed. It's starting a timer, but if you could update the question to show when its work is done that would help.